# Angular - User Registration submit button is not posting into the database

Tags: angular

I am using Angular-11 and Laravel-8 for an application. Laravel as the backend and Angular as the frontend. When I clicked on the submit button in Angular, nothing happens.

Backend (Laravel) model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'mobile_number',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'password',
];
```

register.component.ts:

```js
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoading = false;
  isSubmitted = false;
  signupForm!: FormGroup;
  separateDialCode = true;
  SearchCountryField = SearchCountryField;
  CountryISO = [];
  PhoneNumberFormat = PhoneNumberFormat;
  preferredCountries = [];

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef-whitespace
    private api: ApiService,
    // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef-whitespace
    private token: TokenService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
  ) {}

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createUser();
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  createUser() {
    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      first_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      last_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      mobile_number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      confirm_password: ['', [Validators.required]],
      terms: [false, [Validators.requiredTrue]]
    }, {
      validator: MustMatch('password', 'confirm_password')
    });
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  get f() {
    return this.signupForm.controls;
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.signupForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    const formData = this.signupForm.getRawValue();

    const data = {
      first_name: formData.first_name,
      last_name: formData.last_name,
      email: formData.email,
      mobile_number: formData.mobile_number,
      password: formData.password,
      confirm_password: formData.confirm_password,
      terms: formData.terms
    };

    // tslint:disable-next-line:align
    this.spinnerService.show();
    const header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    console.log(data);
    return this.api.post('register', data, header)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
        data => {
          this.tokenHandler(data);
        },
        error => {
          this.toastr.error(error.message);
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  tokenHandler(data: any) {
    this.toastr.success(data.message);
  }

}
```

signup.html:

```html
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': isSubmitted && f.first_name.errors }" />
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && f.first_name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.first_name.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.first_name.errors.maxlength">First Name cannot be more than 50 characters</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <ngx-intl-tel-input [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': isSubmitted && f.mobile_number.errors }" [cssClass]="'form-control mb-3'" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries" [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true" [searchCountryFlag]="true" [selectFirstCountry]="false"
            [enablePlaceholder]="false" [phoneValidation]="true" name="mobile_phone" formControlName="mobile_number">
          </ngx-intl-tel-input>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && f.mobile_number.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.mobile_number.errors.required">Mobile Number is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.mobile_number.errors.maxlength">Mobile Number cannot be more than 15 characters</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': isSubmitted && f.password.errors }" />
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" formControlName="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': isSubmitted && f.last_name.errors }" />
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && f.last_name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.last_name.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.last_name.errors.maxlength">Last Name cannot be more than 50 characters</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': isSubmitted && f.email.errors }" />
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" formControlName="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': isSubmitted && f.confirm_password.errors }" />
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && f.confirm_password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.confirm_password.errors.required">Confirm Password is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.confirm_password.errors.MustMatch">Passwords must match</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="form-group icheck-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" class="form-control" formControlName="terms" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': isSubmitted && f.terms.errors }">
        <label for="terms">
                 I agree with the <a href="#">terms</a>
                </label>
        <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && f.terms.errors" class="invalid-feedback">Accept Ts & Cs is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-4">
      <button [disabled]="isLoading" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                Sign Up
              </button>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
  </div>
</form>
```

When I clicked on the submit button, I expected it to save into the database, but nothing happen. There is nothing on the console.

When I console.log(data) in the component, I got:

[image: console error]

> When I checked Laravel log, though not in detail, I saw this:   local.ERROR: ErrorException: Array to string conversion ...   Its like the problem is from the mobile_number. I used ngx-intl-tel-input. See the screenshot I sent to you, the code, and also this:

> mobile_number: {number: "2349099887766", internationalNumber: "+234 909 988 7766", nationalNumber: "0909 988 7766", e164Number: "+2349099887766", countryCode: "NG", … assist

How do I resolve this?

Comment: How does angular relate to the database?

Comment: @feihoa - How do you mean, I don't understand?  I can successfully login

Comment: did you see any request in browser's network panel

Comment: The validator "MustMatch" is a validator about the formGroup, I don't know about this, but I imagine that `f.confirm_password.errors.MustMatch` is always null. Really Angular don't show an error in console? BTW add a `console.write("invalid")` if the form is invalid in onSubmit function

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz - I got this in the console:  POST http://localhost:8888/server/api/v1/myapp/signup 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @Eliseo - I set confirm_password to null, the error is still there. What do you mean by BTW add a console.write("invalid"). I tried to do console.write("invalid"), but write is not recognized

Comment: Status code 500 is an error related to your backend, the error is not on angular. Look at your laravel's backend logs to find what is wrong

Comment: sorry was console.log -I mixed different languages :(-. The error 500 is an error in the API. Really you should create your object "data" only with the values you need -you needn't send confirm_password nor term-

Comment: @Eliseo - How do you mean. Kindly explain and assist. When I removed           confirm_password: formData.confirm_password, and terms: formData.terms from const data, the error is no more there but not still posting. When I removed terms, I'm getting Internal Server Error.  The funny thing is that when there's duplicate, the backend detects

Comment: I want to say in the onSubmit() function, you create a "data": `const data = {...}` I want to say that you're sending to the post the object "data" with properties you needn't. You can check if your back-end works (using, e.g. postman and send the json object). I haven't use never laravel, so I can not help you much more

Comment: @Eliseo - When I checked Laravel log, though not in detail, I saw this:   local.ERROR: ErrorException: Array to string conversion ...   Its like the problem is from the mobile_number. I used ngx-intl-tel-input. See the screenshot I sent to you, the code, and also this: mobile_number: {number: "2349099887766", internationalNumber: "+234 909 988 7766", nationalNumber: "0909 988 7766", e164Number: "+2349099887766", countryCode: "NG", …   Kindly assist

Comment: then use `const data={...,mobile_number: formData.mobile_number.number}` (or if you want to save the internationalNumber `formData.mobile_number.internationalNumber`)

Comment: @Eliseo - Thanks so much. It works

Comment: 500 is a back end issue as everyone in the comment said check ur server code first